# Where should I put the .pem file to connect to a EC2 instance via SSH from a containerized Airflow service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, airflow

I am having trouble connecting to a EC2 instance from a dockerized puckel/Airflow service. I don't know where to save the pem file for the SSH connection to grab. How can I make the pem file avaialable for the containers?

Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend not using puckel, it is no longer mantained and now there is an official Docker image

Answer (score 0):

As with any other file - you could copy the pem file to the container while building the docker image, or later by mounting a folder from the host.

For example: You could bind the host folder `/home/myuser/keys` to `/root/keys`. Then the contents of your host's folder will be accessible inside the docker container in `/root/keys`.

[Bind Mounts in Docker](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)